# API returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: angular, angular6

```
var response = await this.http.post(proxyURL, cipherPayLoad, {
  headers: new commonHttp.HttpHeaders(requestHeaders),
  observe: 'response',
  reportProgress: false,
  responseType: 'text',
  withCredentials: false,
}).toPromise();
```

when this request fails and give status code 400, Bad request, I want to parse the all Response Header parameters with their respective values

```
err => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(err['headers']);
  console.log(err['headers'].get('messages'));
  console.log(err['headers'].get('Content-Type'));
})
```

but from the above code I can only able to get content Type

Comment: what output does `console.log(err)` generate?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually represents some kind of faulty data that you have passed. It can be because some integer field value is float, or integer field value is string, etc.

I recommend you use postman and send data in body. Try to remove one one property to identify which exact data format is wrong